# simple and quick tool on linux to watch a http request coming

Tags: http, http-headers

A HTTP request is coming your way, hitting your machine on a port( assumed that you know the request url/route and the port)
what is a simple and quick tool which helps you watch its headers, parameters being passed, using any language, or any tiny web server proxy, any tool.

Being a ruby/rails guy, I quickly created a rails app, set its routes, ran it, and simply followed its logs.

Curious to know how other web app developers deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use WireShark and it is very easy and configurable.

If you use debian or derivates:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

else:

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChapterBuildInstall.html

Comment: :) its not about how to install/uninstall such tools, but how to simply use them say by having a one liner or within 5 sec. You said it is "very easy and configurable", how? Could you please give an example here?

Comment: Wireshark offers much more comfort so its worth waiting 60 secounds instead of 5. using X11 forwarding you can also use it from another pc,... so I dont think thats such a downside!

Comment: Catpure the interface you want and you can filter the packages so you just receive http. When you start capturing, select a package and in the  window at the bottom you can see all the data it contains including the headers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with `tcpdump`. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump). There is also a version for windows.

**edit**
here's the requested example: `tcpdump port 80` (yes, it's that simple). Run it with sudo or as root, otherwise you'll get `no suitable device found`.

If you need more verbose output, add `-v` or `-vv`.

Comment: but how it would make quick and simple? any one liner example?

Comment: great, but cannot find http headers, params easily :), can see loads of tcp level details. Thanks @pduersteler for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use `wireshark` on a Debian-derived GNU/Linux distro:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wireshark wireshark-doc
$ sudo dumpcap -i eth0
```

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /tmp/wireshark_pcapng_eth0...
$ wireshark /tmp/wireshark_pcapng_eth0...
```